# Codeigniter. Добавление массива в базу игнорируя дубликаты

Tags: php, codeigniter

Знаю, что массив можно с помощью `insert_batch` вставить, но при этом мне надо игнорировать дубликаты.

Comment: На сколько мне известно, в  AR CodeIgniter'а нет INSERT IGNORE. Вот есть решение проблемы на англоязычном стэке:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965792/insert-ignore-using-codeigniter

Comment: Спасибо помогли